# Wordpress Post Filter using day of the week

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

i would like to filter the wordpress posts using buttons, there will be few buttons like "Monday, tuesday, wed........" when a user click on a button, i wanna show the articles posted on that day, how can we do this ?

View Image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwDLh.png)

Comment: check this http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/display-popular-posts-by-day-week-month-and-all-time-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one:--**

> This answer may help someone who really wants to customize their
>   filters.
>
> // Do advanced SQL editing for filtering the days of the week

```
add_filter( 'posts_where_request', array( &$this, 'processSQLDelMarkers' ), 99, 2 );

/**
 * Manipulate the pre-flight SQL query to filter on the day of the week.
 * Remove any ##DEL## marker as well as the next character after it
 * @param $where
 * @return mixed
 */
public function processSQLDelMarkers($where, \WP_Query &$query)
{
    // Special gate
    if (stripos($where, '##DEL##') === false) {
        return $where;
    }

    // ... security checks omitted for brevity ...

    /**
     *  Sample where clause before adjustment:
     *  ... AND ihs_postmeta.meta_value != '##DEL##\' AND WEEKDAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(ihs_postmeta.meta_value)) = 4##DEL##' ) ...
     *  becomes
     *  ... AND ihs_postmeta.meta_value != '' AND WEEKDAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(ihs_postmeta.meta_value)) = 4 ) ...
     */
    return preg_replace( '(##DEL##.?)', '', $where );
}
```

> Then using a carefully constructed meta value and dummy compare
>   like so (see the code in the original question) I could achieve the
>   SQL injection:

```
$qv['meta_query'][] = array(
    'key' => '##DEL##\' AND WEEKDAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(ihs_postmeta.meta_value)) = 4##DEL##',
    'value' => $day,
    'compare' => '!='
);
```

> Note: With the right security checks it should not be possible to
>   inject unwanted SQL strings.

**Another way:---**

> This will display the 10 most popular posts of the day.

```
.<?php get_mostpopular("range=daily&limit=10"); ?>
```